# Array counting 858993460 in each slot

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a two dimensional array, which I can use as coordinates for a map to be displayed. For the moment I'm just trying to get a character to display on screen over and over to create an effect in a box with the dimensions of the array. But at each coordinate it just displays some long number (maybe like the slots are empty or something?)
I feel like it might be a loss of data from the class member to the main function, but I'm really just guessing. 
For example, I'm looking for an output something like this:

```
11111
11111
11111
11111
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Map_Blocks
{
    public:
    int Map_Width = 60;
    int Map_Height = 15;
    int Map_Array [15][60];

    int Generate();
    int Display();
};

int Map_Blocks::Generate()
{
    int x, y;
    for(y=0;y<Map_Height;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;y<Map_Width;x++)
        {
            Map_Array[y][x]=1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int Map_Blocks::Display()
{
    int x, y;
    for(y=0;y<Map_Height;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;y<Map_Width;x++)
        {
            cout<<Map_Array[y][x];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    Map_Blocks Size;

    cout<<"Map Width ="<<Size.Map_Width<<endl;
    cout<<"Map Height ="<<Size.Map_Height<<endl;

    Map_Blocks disp;
    disp.Display();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never call `Generate()` to initialize the array's content.

Add:

```
disp.Generate();
```

before the call to `Display()`.

Comment: Hooking this here: the double-`for` loops have their indices messed up, too.

Comment: @Quentin Where?

Comment: @SimonKraemer both inner `for` loops check `y` but iterate with `x`.

Comment: @Quentin Ah! Nice find... I even missed that after your comment.

Comment: A suggestion is to put the call to `Generate()` in a constructor. To not accidentally miss initialization is what they were invented for, after all.

Comment: About the for loop problem that's actually not that way in the real code. Thanks though. The reason it's like that here is I just rewrote the code on my phone and did a lot of copy and pasting...